# How to use codeigniter built-in form validation functions in callback function?

Tags: codeigniter

Hi I am trying to validate a user registration form using codeigniter form validation class. In my form majority of the fields are validated using codeigniter form validation class. But one field 'email' field has to be validated via database whether the email entered by the user is available for registration or not. When I use callback function other field validations like required|trim|xss_clean|valid_email etc don't work.

I don't want to write code manually for each of the validation like valid_email that are already exist in CI. When I use callback function for this field the CI form validations don't apply. 
Here is my code:

My Form:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name"/>
<input type="text" name="last_name"/>
<input type="text" name="email"/>
<input type="password" name="password"/>
<input type="password" name="cpassword"/>
```

Here is my controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name','First Name','required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name','Last Name','required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','valid_email|xss_clen|required|callback_email_check');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|min_length[6]|max_length[20]|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword','Retype Password','callback_password_match');
```

My callback function for email_check:

```
public function email_check()
{
    $email=$this->input->post('email'); 

    if($this->home_mod->email_available($email))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('email_check', 'Another user with this email is already registered. Please try different email');   
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

Now after all that, form validation rules valid_email|required etc don't apply. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is already a validation for this called `is_unique` to use `is_unique[table_name.table_column_name]`

Answer (score 0):

All your code looks correctly formatted, but try returning true after the check if it passes. So like this:

```
public function email_check()
{
    $email=$this->input->post('email'); 

    if($this->home_mod->email_available($email))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('email_check', 'Another user with this email is already registered. Please try different email');   
        return FALSE;
    } return true; //Add here

}
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not fix the problem.

Comment: Is your controller function and your email_check() function in the same file/location?